# SharePoint Search and Search Scrope boxes stacked on top of one another

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint site I am attempting to brand, and one of the requests was to place the search control and search text field on top of each other (inline?). I have seen online some jQuery magic flip the positioning of these boxes in order to change the appearance, as described here:
http://labs.steveottenad.com/reskinrestyle-the-sharepoint-2010-advanced-search-box/

What I am looking to do is make the search control with the drop down menu to be placed on top of the text input box so that they are stacked on top of one another. While the aforementioned article uses jQuery, I'm thinking that CSS could be used to complete my request as well.

This is my masterpage code for the search area right now. I believe it's kind of messy, which I know doesn't help.. so I am having difficulty recognizing which div is which search component.

```
<td style="width: 2px">
<div id="s4-searcharea" class="s4-search s4-rp"></div>
<div class="customSearch">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
<SPSWC:SearchBoxEx id="SearchBox" runat="server" 
GoImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif" 
GoImageUrlRTL="/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif" 
DropdownModeEx=ShowDD 
DropdownWidth="120"
UseSiteDefaults="true"      
QueryPromptString="Keyword(s)"
FrameType="None" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{551E15C2-XXX}"/>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                       
    </div>
    </td>
```

I'm thinking that I will need to use the display:inline attribute and maybe assign a z-index value to both classes? Any help setting this up would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of the article you are referencing in your question. I'm sure this is already taken care of, but to whomever may stumble across it in the future, you will need to use javascript/jquery to alter the markup of the search control. By default, the scope dropdown is in a different table cell, and you wont be able to get a stacked appearance using CSS alone. Try something like this:

```
var scopedropdown = $('.ms-sbscopes select');
$('.ms-sbrow .ms-sbcell').eq(1).prepend(scopedropdown);
```

I understand that using .eq() is hacky, but SP2010 gives no unique class to the cell you need to target. Once you get your scope dropdown into the right cell, go to town with the CSS to get it looking the way you want. You can also use .append() instead of .prepend() if you want the dropdown below the searchbox.

Also note that the search button is included in a different cell, so you may have some issues with the width of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Sharepoint installation I can test this with, but I feel obligated to try ;).  if you can get your searchbox to look like the demo's searchbox, then this code should get you a great start on using css to get a nice vertical stacked look.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                //Hide Default search Icon
                $('.srch-gosearchimg').hide();  
//removed the line below, your html template included it already
                //$('.ms-sbplain').wrap('<div class="customSearchBox">');   
    //save the current 'scopes' drop down, we're about to delete its current location
                var scopes = $('.ms-sbscopes').clone();
    //delete the standard 'scopes' drop down
                $('.ms-sbscopes').remove();
    //wrap our scopes Copy in a Div.  change this class with css to position it correctly.

//removed this line, let's just get it to show up again.
//                    scopes.wrap("<div class=''>");
    //this code sticks the 'scopes' dd ahead of the '.ms-sbplain' item, not behind it like the demo
                $('.customSearchBox').prepend(scopes);
            });     
        </script>
```

Comment: My apologies.

I have a SharePoint masterpage that has an advanced search control enabled, and currently has the search scope and search text input fields side by side.

What I would like to do is configure these two items to be positioned one on top of the other, in an attempt to some space in the title area. 

There are some resources that describe the use of jQuery to flip both the search scope and input fields such as this:
http://labs.steveottenad.com/reskinrestyle-the-sharepoint-2010-advanced-search-box/

What I want to do however, is place the search scope on TOP of the input field.

Comment: k, i'll help you rework your question so you can maybe get an answer from the community.

Comment: Ouch, i don't have enough privileges to edit your question.  You'll have to do edit it.

Comment: Sadly, I'm good with jQuery, but not Sharepoint.  I can help rework your question though.  Find the css for the search box and scope box, put it into the question.  Put the link in from your comment, so people can see why you want/need jQuery.  Finally, while waiting for an answer, try altering the css for the search boxes on your own and see if you can get them on top of each other ;)

Comment: Well, that definitely removed the scope.. whether its hidden somewhere or was completely lost I don't know, but its not there anymore. I'm thinking the placement of my div classes might be wrong.. can anyone confirm?

Comment: I noticed that the <td> element is set to 2 px wide.

Comment: edited the jQuery, I took out some lines of code you may not need.

Comment: Would the width of the TD element effect the placement of these items? When viewed in the browser, the <TD> element is visibly larger than 2px wide. The revised code placed the search scopes back onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at the html rather than the aspx code if you are working with styles. For this sort of thing I usually use FireBug or Chrome Inspect Element to find styles that work, then copy them to the master page stylesheet.

You may be able to do what you want with css alone, though I suspect you will still need jquery as in the example you found - css can't reorder elements or remove a table.

Comment: Thanks, but I used FireBug already to find the styles and then applied the custom div classes to both. I then tried applying display:inline, display:block, to see if those would stack the two boxes, but they will not.

Any jQuery known that can do this?